# iptables rule to deny/REJECT *outgoing* traffic to all but one IP

Tags: iptables

Please suggest iptables rules to deny OUTgoing traffic, except for one specific IP address.

The purpose is to allow communication between the server and one other server only, and deny anything else.  But the specific port(s) open will vary.

Comment: What rules did you try so far? Remember, that a server usually needs also `DNS` resolution to work.

Comment: It will only be communicating with one other computer, by IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to renounce to `DNS` name resolution, you only need to allow:

1. Responses to remotely initiated connections,
2. New connections to the chosen IP address (e.g. `192.0.50.1`)

This sums up to:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.0.50.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```